# R : ggplotを使用した散布図の色・サイズ分けについて

Tags: r, ggplot2

以下のようなデータを使用した場合の散布図において、
任意に色とサイズを指定したいです。
Regは1~6の整数を取りますが、1の時のサイズを大きく、
6の時のサイズを小さくしたいと考えています。
データ名 Res

```
 Reg  h  w sex
1 1  180 60 M
2 2  155 50 F
3 3  160 55 F
4 2  170 65 M
....
```

以下のようなコードで実行した場合、

```
p_colour <- c("red","darkorange","yellow","green","blue","grey40")
p_size <- c(6,5,4,3,2,1)

base <- ggplot(Res, aes(x = h, y = w, size = Reg, colour = as.factor(Reg)))
points <- base + geom_point()
change_colors <- points + scale_colour_manual(values = p_colour)
change_sizes <- change_colors + scale_size_manual(values = p_size)
plot(change_sizes)
```

下記のように離散値へ連続値を与えたといった旨のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

どの様に変更すれば解決できますでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

ggplot関数でbaseを作成する時に，size = Reg (これだとsizeにint型が入る)ためです。
なので，その一行をを以下のように修正すると，おそらくは望んでいるplotが描けるかと思います:

```
base <- ggplot(Res, aes(x = h, y = w, size = as.factor(Reg), colour = as.factor(Reg)))
```